# access attributes of one class for use in another class in python add-in

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, python-addin

I want to get combobox attribute 'dem' and use it for further processing in class ExtentData. But I am not sure how to get attributes from one class to another for processing in pythonaddin. In following code, I want attribute 'dem' from class ComboBoxFrame right after if statement in class ExtentData. Any suggestion would be appreciative.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import wx

class ExtentData(object):
"""Implementation for ExtentData_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
        self.cursor = 5
        self.shape = 'Rectangle'

    def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    """"""

    dlg = None
    extent = rectangle_geometry

    if extent != None:
        self.dlg = ComboBoxFrame()


class ComboBoxFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Input Data Selection', size=(350, 300))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        DemList = ['DEM1', 'DEM2', 'DEM3']
        self.Dem = wx.ComboBox(panel, -1, "", (15, 30), wx.DefaultSize,DemList, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnSelect, self.Dem)

        self.btnApply = wx.Button(panel, label="Apply", pos=(65, 200))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id=self.btnApply.GetId())
        self.Show(True)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Show(False)

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        dem = str(event.GetValue())

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code imports wx but does not specifically mention wxPython.  I would probably create and use a tag for wxpython to try and target those with that expertise.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue with the inclusion of line 'global extent' right above 'extent = rectangle_geometry'. This way, attributes were available for all other classes in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the inclusion of line 'global extent' right above 'extent = rectangle_geometry'. This way, attributes were available for all other classes in the script.

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way to do this, without using global variables, is to define an attribute in either the class's `__init__` method (making them instance members), or in the class declaration itself (making them class members).

For example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.extent = (0, 0, 0, 0)

class B():
    extent = (1, 2, 3, 4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    print a.extent # prints (0, 0, 0, 0)
    print B.extent # prints (1, 2, 3, 4)
    print A.extent # results in AttributeError: class A has no attribute 'extent'
```

Comment: This is neat. 
In my case, class A is calling class B (class B is wx.Frame). I didn't stop 'self.dlg' and it is in some sort of continuing loop. Please suggest how to kill this event once I accomplish something in class B.

Comment: That sounds like a wxPython question which I can't help you with. I suggest you ask a new question. Probably on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).